# Problem adding resources in MS Project

Tags: ms-project

When I assign a resource in Project, it lists the resource in the resource column and creates a new line listing only the resource.  How do I turn this off?

Comment: Please provide a little more detail in order for the community to better assist you.

Answer (score 1):

When you refer to the new line listing the resource, is it possible that you are looking at the Resource Sheet view perhaps in a split screen?

MS Project will by default create a new resource for you if you enter a resource name that has not been used before. Likewise - if you enter a typo in the resource name Project will assume that it's a new resource and add an extra resource into the Resource Sheet.

It's difficult to know without more detail - please consider sharing a screen image of the situation with a little more detail. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This would normally happen in the Task Usage view. The purpose of this view is to list each resource assignment below the relevant task. Check if you're using the Task Usage view and if yes, try switching to another view.